# Optimise frequent average calculation

Tags: java, math

I'm calculating an average of floats. More specifically the azimuth value in radians.
These floats are inside of an array that has a maximum size of 40.

Every time I receive a new azimuth value from the sensors, I add the new value to history array and calculate the average. My goal is to calculate the average without having to keep summing all the 40 elements for each 5 milliseconds. Is there a way to do this? Thanks

**My current code:**

```java
public void addAzimuthToHist(float azimuth){
        if (azimuthHist.size() >= 40) {
           // If history exceeds 40, then remove first item in queue.
            azimuthLastPoll = azimuthHist.poll();
        } else {
            azimuthLastPoll = 0;
        }

        lastAddedToAzimuthHist = azimuth;
        azimuthHist.offer(azimuth); // Add new azimuth value to history
    }

/**
     * Get average of azimuth history
     */
    private float averageAzimuthHist(){
        if (azimuthHist.size() < 40) {
            Iterator<Float> iterator = azimuthHist.iterator();
            float sum = 0;
            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                float aziumth = iterator.next();
                sum += aziumth;
            }
            lastAvg = sum / azimuthHist.size();
        } else {
            lastAvg = (lastAvg - azimuthLastPoll + lastAddedToAzimuthHist) / azimuthHist.size();
        }

        return lastAvg;
    }
// Callback when the senosors emit a new Value(each 5 milliseconds)
gravityMag.setOnAzimuthChange(azimuth -> {
            addAzimuthToHist(azimuth);
            float currentAverage = averageAzimuthHist();

            double deg = Math.toDegrees(currentAverage);
            getReactApplicationContext()
            .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
            .emit("HeadingUpdated", (int) Math.round((deg + 360) % 360));

        });
```

With the snippet below I was trying to 'increment' the average but the results are wrong.

`lastAvg = (lastAvg - azimuthLastPoll + lastAddedToAzimuthHist) / azimuthHist.size();`

Comment: can you store the last sum and count in memory? How long will this need to be kept in memory though? Does this need thread safety?

Comment: A difficulty with averaging azimuths is, if for example your azimuths go from -pi to pi, the average of 3.14 radians (179.9 degrees) and -3.14 radians is not 0 but pi.

Comment: @dmuir So if we cahnge to degrees (0 - 360) we should not have that problem right?

Comment: @Lucas Gomes, no there is the same problem whatever the units and wherever you put the jump. The average of 1 degree and 359 degrees is 0, not (359+1)/2 = 180.

Answer (score 1):

well with some math, the average of the last N elements is:

```
el_1 + el_2 + ... + el_N-1 + el_N
---------------------------------
                 N
```

then with some manipulation you will get:

```
// separate the last element
el_1 + el_2 + ... + el_N-1   el_N
-------------------------- + ----
            N                  N

// multiply and divide by N-1
el_1 + el_2 + ... + el_N-1   N-1    el_N
-------------------------- * ---- + ----
            N                N-1     N

// switch the denominator
el_1 + el_2 + ... + el_N-1   N-1    el_N
-------------------------- * ---- + ----
            N-1               N       N
// notice that the fist element is the average of the first N-1 element (previous average)
                             N-1    el_N
average_first_N-1_elements * ---- + ----
                              N       N

//simplify (same denominator)
                            
average_first_N-1_elements *  N-1 + el_N
----------------------------------------
                  N
```

in other words, if you have the last average, and you want to "add" another number, you will have to apply this formula:

```
// lastAvg : variable with the last average
// numberOfElements : int counting the number of signals you have received from the sensor
// lastAddedToAzimuthHist : number to add to the average
lastAvg = (lastAvg * numberOfElements + lastAddedToAzimuthHist) / (numberOfElements + 1);
numberOfElements = numberOfElements + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would move the adding of new values to total sum into your `addAzimuthToHist` method and substract old values while removing from the array. That helps you to get rid of the loops in your `averageAzimuthHist` and simplify additionaly the calculating of the average. Not tested example just to give you an idea of what I'm tring to say:

Assuming you have defined fields

```
float sum = 0f;
Queue<Float> azimuthHist = ...
```

then

```
public void addAzimuthToHist(float azimuth){
    sum += azimuth;
    azimuthHist.offer(azimuth);  //azimuthHist.add(azimuth);
    if (azimuthHist.size() > 40) {
        sum -= azimuthHist.poll();
    }
}

private float averageAzimuthHist(){
    if (azimuthHist.isEmpty()) return 0f;
    int divisor = azimuthHist.size();
    return  sum /divisor;
}
```